# Laravel: Query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Might be stupid question, how to correctly state the ID in select statement?

```
public function generatefinalconfirmation($id) {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
        $flightin = DB::select('SELECT b.bookingname, f.origin FROM Bookings B JOIN Flights F ON B.Flightin = F.FlightId WHERE B.ID = id');
}
```

That code give me all the data while `where b.id = $id` give me an error message.

Thanks

Edit: Thanks all for the answers, sorry for all the rookie mistake

Comment: Watch your quotes. Did you mean `where b.id=' . $id`? Variables don't expand (is that the right term???) in single quotes

Comment: If the TO meant that, the query is open to SQL injections

Comment: "_...give me an error message_" What error message would that be?

Comment: And `b.id` is not the same as `B.ID`

Answer (score 3):

This way you prevent SQL injections and make your code more readable:

```
public function generatefinalconfirmation($id) {
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
        $flightin = DB::table('Bookings AS B')
                ->select([ 'b.bookingname', 'f.origin'])
                ->join('Flights AS F', 'B.Flightin', 'F.FlightId')
                ->where('B.ID', $id);
}
```

Comment: Might need the `as` keyword in there for the aliases. I've seen QueryBuilder be picky about that.